# PWDENCRYPT in user-defined function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions, random

In writing a random number function, I have learned that you can’t use `NEWID()` or `RAND()` inside a user function because they are non-deterministic.

I have also discovered that I can use `PWDENCRYPT` and get away with it. I would have thought that that was also non-deterministic. It certainly gives me a random-enough value for testing purposes (I’m not trying to simulate quantum physics here).

My questions:

- is `PWDENCRYPT` really acceptable inside a user function (i.e., it works now, but can I expect it to keep working)?
- is it random enough (for a reasonable definition of random)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PWDENCRYPT` is kind of deprecated, so no, you shouldn't be using it now, and you certainly shouldn't expect it to work indefinitely *in any fashion* - deterministic or not. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx):

> PWDENCRYPT is an older function and might not be supported in a future release of SQL Server. Use [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) instead. HASHBYTES provides more hashing algorithms.

I don't know that anybody can answer your second question. How do you define "random enough"?

Also, just to be clear, `NEWID()` and `RAND()` are disallowed in functions not because they are non-deterministic, but rather because they are considered "side effecting" - even though there is nothing you or I could assume about how these functions affect anything, other than incrementing some internal random number sequence generator.

And there are easy workarounds to that, anyway - e.g. create a view and have the function reference the view, pass `NEWID()` into the function, etc.

In addition to `PWDENCRYPT()`, other functions that are also obviously not deterministic (such as `GETDATE()`, `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and others) **are** allowed. Example:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.what()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT @@DBTS + @@CPU_BUSY + @@CONNECTIONS
    + DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), SYSUTCDATETIME()));
END
GO

SELECT dbo.what();
```

The function will be marked as non-deterministic (which you can confirm with `OBJECTPROPERTY()`), which can limit how the UDF is in turn used, but it isn't the case that "non-deterministic functions are not allowed inside user-defined functions." Even though that's what a lot of people have written, it isn't strictly true.

In fact, `RAND()` is [documented to be deterministic when a seed is provided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx); `RAND(5);` is demonstrably deterministic. But it still isn't allowed in a function (this returns the same side-effecting error):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.who()
RETURNS decimal(20,19)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT RAND(5));
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

PWDENCRYPT isn't officially deprecated yet, so it will almost certainly be around for quite some time.

My concern would be that it *"uses the current version of the password hashing algorithm"* which means the behaviour could change without notice. Who's to say it will continue to be sufficiently random, perhaps instead going deterministic like Hashbytes?